# Angularjs seperate login page and home page without backend

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, socket.io

My basic question is;

How to implement two seperate page(everything is different,css, js, html file) login and home page in 'Just using' client side? I mean think like a classical login mechanism. User will come to login page and give a credential,then 'redirect' to home page. I need to seperate this two page because themes and the other things are different. Also after this step (login step) I want to continue with SPA with Angularjs,mongoDb,socket.io and Nodejs.

In stackoverflow I found couple implementation with ASP.NET Web API or other backend technologies. But I don't want to use ASP.NET framework for just login page. As I said I will not need ASP.NET framework after user logged in.

Also I found couple authentication implementation on Angular.js but every example using same templates and styles for login page and home page.But I cannot use these styles and html code cause dom's are too different.

So any suggestion or idea for this problem will be great. Thanks.

Comment: Authentication/Authorization without backend is not secure. Of course you can do this but DONT DO IT. It is bad for you and it is bad for users. Client only authentication requires you to pass the username and password to the client through javascript and any body can view them. However, you can take advantage of libraries out there that can do OAUTH2 securely without any backend of your won. Check out http://adodson.com/hello.js/

Comment: Basically my question wasn't about authentication. I can handle it some way but my question is how can I do seperate this two page. By the way thanks for link.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean be separate home page and login page. Any screen shots and/or source code samples can help to clarify. In majority of application home page and login page are what they mean: two separate pages.

Comment: @Aidin Yes screenshot will be look like this. This is login: http://i.hizliresim.com/99vrl5.png and this is home page:http://i.hizliresim.com/qm9NnR.png As you can see this two page html and css are too different.This mean is:two seperate page.